# Python regex: how to check if a character in a string is within the span of a regex matched substring?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex pattern, which I used on a large piece of text (a single string). Several discontiguous regions of the original text matches the regexp. Now, I'm attempting to build a state machine, to iterate over the text and do different things based on the char at a position, and whether this position is within the span of a regex match.

With RE.finditer(text), I can find all substrings, and extract their spans, thus I have a list of tuples to work with e.g.

(1, 5)
(10, 15)
(20, 55),
etc.

With this information, given the index of the character in my string, I can write an algorithm to see if that character is a part of a regex string. For example, given character 6, i can go through the list of spans and determine that it is not part of a matched substring.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,

JW

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a parser FSM which (among otehr things) tokenizes comma characters, only when they are not escaped. Do you really want to write your own state machine, not just a grammar and let *antlr/lex* create the FSM for you?

Comment: Ye kinda, my lex/yacc is a bit fuzzy :).

Comment: No need to write a parser FSM when all you needed was a regex that matches escaped commas inside identifiers. Now then, do you want to capture all of *`bbbb/,ccccc`* as one token, or three?

Comment: In one token, since I'm ignoring commas if they're part of an escape seuqnce.

Comment: Ok, I added a regex that does that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It sounds like you want to write your own parser FSM which (among other things) tokenizes comma characters, only when they are not escaped. 
The following regex works for an identifier, possibly containing escaped commas. You could use this with antlr/lex:

```
input = r'aaaaa,bbbb/,ccccc,dddddd,'

pat = re.compile(r'((\w+|/,)+)')

for mat in re.finditer(pat, input):
    ... do stuff with mat.group(0)
```

---

(Original answer:
That could be a good solution, but you're not giving us enough context to tell.

Does character occur once or multiply? If it occurs once, you could just check whether the index from `string.find(char)` lies inside the spans of the regex matches.

Is character any arbitrary character - give us a specific example?
Why are you doing this on a per-character basis? Presumably you're not sequentially checking multiple chars?

Is your desired result boolean (*'Yes, char was found inside the span of some regex match'*)? and what you do for the case where char was found OUTside a regex match?

Comment: I have a state machine which iterates through the string and performs specific actions based on what the character is and ALSO whether the character is a part of regex match. For example doing something if the character is "," and not a part of a regex-matched substring (so I wanna ignore all the ',''s if it's within a substring matched by a specific regex). So I will dealing multiple instances of the same character, and need to know whether each of them is a part of a regex-matched substring. Hope this clears it up, thanks.

Comment: Still not enough context. **Please post a specific example of string input and output.** Why are you writing a generalized state machine - is that your goal or just the implementation you picked? **Why** are you trying to match a comma characters against regex matches - what specific problem is that intended to solve?

Comment: If you only want to ignore a range of ignoreChars within your matches, surely apply `string.translate(...deleteChars)` to them?

Comment: This is just an arbitrary example: scan through aaaaa,bbbb/,ccccc,dddddd, I want to save the string between 2 ","s, however /, is considered a special escape sequence and not an actual ",". So I iterate through the string, save text every time "," is encountered, however, I don't want to save text if "/," is encountered. So I create a regex to match all the escape sequences in my string, and given this information, every time my state machine encounters a ",", I need to know whether that "," is a part of an escape sequence or not.

Comment: I actually want to preserved the characters, so I can't just delete chars. So far I already know that the solution I proposed would work, I'm just curious as to whether there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Sounds like you never wanted to match the optional trailing comma in the first place. If so, either use `input.split(',')` or else use a regex with an optional lookahead assertion to catch the comma *`(?=,)?`*

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
Here's a regex which will grab the text between `,` ignoring escaped `,`:

```
(?=<,)(?:[^,]|(?=</),)(?=,)
```

**Original Answer**
Here is some pseudo python code that should do what you're looking for:

```
pattern = re.compile(...)
pos = 0

while (match = pattern.search(haystack, pos)) {
  for (i in range(pos, match.start)
    //These chars are outside the match.

  for (i in group(0))
    //The chars are in the match

  pos = match.end

//Finish with the rest of the chars not matched
for (i in range(pos, len(haystack))
  //These chars are outside the match.
```

Comment: `haystack`? That is soooo PHP